# Flutter application after killed show password screen - ZEGOCLOUD

Tags: android, flutter, zegocloud

I have a Flutter application that uses [ZegoCloud CallKit](https://www.zegocloud.com/doc/callkit/Call%20Kit/main/Quick%20start%20(with%20call%20invitation)/eb1d3c42) for handling voice calls. While incoming calls function perfectly in both foreground and background app states, an issue arises when the app is killed by the user and a call comes in. In this scenario:

- The device initially displays the call screen with options to answer
  or reject.
- If the user chooses to answer, the device switches to the lock
  screen, prompting for password input.
- Only after entering the password does the call screen reappear with
  the call already answered.

There are app permissions config

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<!--for bring app to foreground from background in Android 10 -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS" />

<activity
...
 android:showWhenLocked="true"
 android:turnScreenOn="true"
</activity>
```

Any help with this I would greatly appreciate it since it's been a week and I can't solve this problem.

Thanks